# in angular 16 project when we call REST Api from project it will shows error but when we direct call from POSTMAN or browser it will shows data

Tags: angular, express, mean-stack, meanjs

1. angular 16 project service  data call

getData() {   this.regionService.getAllRegion().subscribe(data => {
this.regionValue = data;

})}

2. Service Data call rest Api

```
getAllRegion(): Observable<RegionI> {      const regionUrl = this.serverUrl + '/getRegion';     return this.httpClient.get<RegionI>(regionUrl); // return an observable
```

```
}
```

3. data type list Observable<RegionI>

   ```
    export interface RegionI {

        region_name: string;
        created_by: string;
        region_code: string;
        region_id: string;
        created_date: Date;
        status: boolean;

   }
   ```
4. json data calll result
   [{"created_date":"2023-11-27T01:59:35.280Z","_id":"6557c94afa43c40a54b3157d","region_name":"AFRICA","created_by":"TINKU","region_code":"AFR","region_id":"RE3","status":true}]
5. this will be shown in postman and also direct calling in web browser
6. same above code running perfect using json server with same result
7. NodeJs code as written as

   api.get('/getRegion',function( req , res ){

   ```
    Region.find().then((data) => {

        if(!data) {
            console.log(!data);
            res.json("no data found");
        }
        else {

            res.status(200).json(data);
            console.log(data);
        }
   ```

   });
   });
8. url call
   public static Live_Web_Server_Path = 'http://localhost:9003'; 'REST Api Server Node, Express, mongo Db'
   public static json_Web_Server_Path = 'http://localhost:3000';  "json server"
9. angular 16 project running fine with JSON_SERVER but when REST API is calling from Node server

then return as Observable but data will not be fetched

but direct REST API call result shown using postman or web browser
[{"created_date":"2023-11-27T01:59:35.280Z","_id":"6557c94afa43c40a54b3157d","region_name":"AFRICA","created_by":"TINKU","region_code":"AFR","region_id":"RE3","status":true}]

error shows when api calling from project

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:9003/master/getRegion' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
region.component.ts:50

```
   GET http://localhost:9003/master/getRegion net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)
```

region.component.ts:50 ERROR HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: 'Unknown Error', url: 'http://localhost:9003/master/getRegion', ok: false, …}error:

Comment: postman is a development tool which doesn't enforce cors like browser does

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable cors for the route on the server side

```
var cors = require('cors');

var corsOptions = {
  origin: 'http://localhost:9003',
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200
};

// Allow all
app.use(cors(corsOptions));

api.get('/getRegion',function( req , res ){
 res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'http://localhost:9003');

 Region.find().then((data) => {

     if(!data) {
         console.log(!data);
         res.json("no data found");
     }
     else {

         res.status(200).json(data);
         console.log(data);
     }
}); 
});
```

or [enable cors through proxy config](https://www.stackhawk.com/blog/angular-cors-guide-examples-and-how-to-enable-it/#proxy-requests-to-enable-cors-in-angular)